# It is exactly a palindrome, but my code says it isn't

Tags: python-3.x

```
s=input()
r=''
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i]=='(' or s[i]==')' or s[i]=='[' or s[i]==']':
        r += s[i]
t = True
for i in range(len(r)//2):
    if r[i] != r[len(r)-i-1]:
    t = False
print(str(t))
```

I think the code with input '[()]' must return True, but it returns False.
Can you answer why? I cannot guess..
I have tried `print(r==r[::-1])`, but it says False, too.

Comment: Are you only trying to check for a palindrome, or are you actually trying to check if the parenthesis are balanced? these are entirely difference problems.

Comment: Your code won't compile for me, your indentation is incorrect

Comment: If you only try to solve for palindrome, what about `return s == s[::-1]`?

Comment: well of course it's false... r[0] != r[3] because '[' != ']' or am I seeing wrong here ?

Comment: wow, I could not think that truth..